# Integrity error where try to save a supplier invoices

Tags: odoo, invoice

I build a module who increase stock on supplier invoices. Work fine on devel server but when I pun on work server I have this error. How can I corret this error?

```
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following: - deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it - creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: Purchase Order Line - purchase.order.line]
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrity Error on OpenERP occur because of two possibility (mentioned on the description of error):

- When you create or update a record, a mandatory field is not correctly set or is not filled. What field? One of field in your object (mentioned). In your case: purchase.order.line.
- When you delete a record, the record you want to delete is used by another record and set as a mandatory field (required) from the python code.

My guess, if you get the error when you create/update a record (Purchase Order), maybe you create/update the order lines, but one of mandatory field in order lines is empty.